# change the background attribute of td using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have many td in a html document containing background attribute. I want to change the path of the background of the td.Following is one example of td:

```
<td background="/v/vspfiles/templates/AlligatorPerform/images/Grid_Single_Divider_Vert.gif"> 
<img width="3" height="3" src="http://alligatorperformanceblog.com/vspfiles/templates/AlligatorPerform/images/clear1x1.gif"> 
</td>
```

in the above example i want to change

```
background="/v/vspfiles/templates/AlligatorPerform/images/Grid_Single_Divider_Vert.gif"
```

to

```
background="http://alligatorperformanceblog.com/vspfiles/templates/AlligatorPerform/images/Grid_Single_Divider_Vert.gif"
```

can anyone please help me how to do it.

Comment: you want to change the background of every td?

Comment: yes i want to change the background of all the td which has background attribute

Comment: i really hope you're not using tables for layout. that clear pixel makes me worried

Comment: i am using tables the td is inside the table only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [has attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) of jquery to select all the td with background attribute

```
$("td[background]").each(function(){
  $(this).attr("background","http://alligatorperformanceblog.com/vspfiles/templates/AlligatorPerform/images/Grid_Single_Divider_Vert.gif");
});
```